# Change point marker in GeoJSON layer in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, wfs

I successfully loaded a WFS in Leaflet, with https://cdn.rawgit.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms/gh-pages/dist/leaflet.wms.js if I recall;

```
var start_at_zoom = 10;

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    // pour afficher seulement une ou deux ou plus, données dans l'infobulle
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.appelation) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.appelation + '</br>' + feature.properties.legende) ;
    }
}

function loadGeoJson(data) {
   // console.log(data);
    $("#total").html(data.features.length);
    featureLayer.clearLayers();
    featureLayer.addData(data);
}

map.on('moveend', load_wfs);

function load_wfs() {
    if (map.getZoom() > start_at_zoom) {
        var geoJsonUrl = 'http://mappingforyou.eu/geoserver/wfs?';
        var defaultParameters = {
            service: 'WFS',
            version: '1.0.0',
            request: 'getFeature',
            typeName: 'worldmap:france.patrim.mh.toutpoint',
            maxFeatures: 300,
            outputFormat: 'text/javascript',
            format_options: 'callback: getJson',
            srsName: 'EPSG:4326'
        };

        var customParams = {
            bbox: map.getBounds().toBBoxString()
        };
        var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters, customParams);
        console.log(geoJsonUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters));

        $.ajax({
            jsonp: false,
            url: geoJsonUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters),
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
            success: loadGeoJson
        });
    } else {
        featureLayer.clearLayers();
    }
}

function styled(feature) {
    return {
        weight: 9,
        opacity: 1,
        color: color,
        fillColor: fillColor,
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
    };
}  
  // specify popup options 
    var customOptions =
        {
        maxHeight: 200, maxWidth: 200
        }

var featureLayer = new L.GeoJSON(
null, {
    style: styled(color= 'Peru', fillColor = 'Peru'),
    onEachFeature: function popUpall(feature, layer) {
        //console.info(feature);
        var out = [];
        if (feature.properties) {
            for (var key in feature.properties) {
                out.push(key + ": " + feature.properties[key]);
            }
            layer.bindPopup(out.join("<br />"), customOptions);
        }
    }
});
```

But I need to use this custom marker for point markers, instead of the default one:

```
var markerOptions = {
    radius: 3,
    fillColor: '#0099FF',
    color: "#fff",
    weight: 3,
    opacity: 0.5,
    fillOpacity: 0.5
};
```

How could how to do that ? I can change the colors for areas, but not point features.

Comment: Your code does not use Leaflet WMS plugin, it just loads GeoJSON layer through WFS service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify default marker for GeoJSON layer points you have to use `pointToLayer` option when creating layer (reading docs and tutorials can actually help, see https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-pointtolayer and https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/).

In your case code for creating GeoJSON layer could then look something like this:

```
var featureLayer = new L.GeoJSON(null, {
  style: styled(color= 'Peru', fillColor = 'Peru'),
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    var circleMarker = L.circleMarker(latlng, {
      radius: 3,
      fillColor: '#0099FF',
      color: "#fff",
      weight: 3,
      opacity: 0.5,
      fillOpacity: 0.5
    });
    return(circleMarker);
  }
  onEachFeature:  function (feature, layer) {
    var out = [];
    if (feature.properties) {
      for (var key in feature.properties) {
        out.push(key + ": " + feature.properties[key]);
      }
      layer.bindPopup(out.join("<br />"), customOptions);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you! I just had to add a comma to

  return(circleMarker);
  },

and it worked fine. my line with "peru" was to remove too.